# GStreamer + OpenCV video processing problem

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I am planning on doing VideoCapture from OpenCV for video file stream/live rtsp stream. However, the VideoCapture has alot of latency when used in my program so i decided to use the gstreamer pipeline instead. For example, i used

```
VideoCapture capVideo("filesrc location=CarsDriving.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink ", CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

My program is able to run but if i were to do something like

```
capVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

It always returns -1 because GStreamer has this warnings

[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/Downloads/opencv-4.4.0/source/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (898) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query duration of stream
[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/Downloads/opencv-4.4.0/source/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=1, duration=-1

How do i get the frame count in opencv if i use gstreamer for the video pipeline? I need the framecount for exceptions and also video processing techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bug** which @alekhin mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10324) and [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14834). Also mentioned how to fix. After changing you should rebuild opencv.

**Also you said:**

> However, the VideoCapture has alot of latency when used in my program
> so i decided to use the gstreamer pipeline instead.

rtsp cameras generaly streams as `h264/h265` encoded data. If you are trying to decode that data via on CPU but not GPU, it will not give you much increasing about speed. Why don't you choose `CAP_FFMPEG` flag instead of `CAP_GSTREAMER`? `CAP_FFMPEG` will be faster than `CAP_GSTREAMER`

Comment: in this case, i will need to use opencv3.4 right? Because currently i am on version 4.4. This is something i found online although i have not verified it yet. Someone mentioned when you create a videoCapture from filename.mp4, opencv will use ffmpeg for demux and decode. But the Ubuntu apt version of ffmeg on jetson is cpu only. So i am trying to workaround it by using a gst pipeline

Comment: oh just to be clear, i am using a video file for debugging purposes, but actual usage is to do a rtsp stream

Comment: You dont need to change version, you need to add a line of code mentioned in post, and then rebuild opencv 4.4.0

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I am experiencing exactly the same issue. When looking at the second link on GitHub I see a pull request, but not a single line of code to add, as you suggested. Could you please be so kind and elaborate a bit on this?